# How I can add cc when sending email from R with SendGrid

Tags: r, email, sendgrid

I'd like to send emails from R with many addresses in "to" and "cc"

Following this example https://www.r-bloggers.com/automatically-write-and-email-reports-with-r-sendgrid-displayr/ I can send email to 1 address.

After some experiments I cam send email to few readers in "to" with code like this (actual API key and emails are removed)

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

body = paste("\\nDear friend,",
             "\\n\\n",
             "\\n\\nI'm testing email.",
             "\\n\\n",
             "\\n\\nKind regards,",
             "\\n\\nYuriy",sep="")


key1       <-  "SG.****" #enter your API Key here

readers <- c("m1@example.com",  "m2@example.com")
copiers <- c("m3@example.com",  "m4@example.com")


to.email   <-  paste0('{\"email\": \"', 
                      paste( readers, collapse = '\"}, {\"email\": \"') , 
                      '\"}')
cc.email   <-  paste0(' {\"email\": \"',
                      paste(copiers, collapse = '\"}}, {\"cc\":{\"email\": \"'), 
                      '\"}')
from.email <-  "from@example.com"
subject    <-  "Testing Sendgrid"
message.body  <-  body


msg  <- sprintf('{\"personalizations\":
        [{\"to\": [ %s]}],
          \"from\": {\"email\": \"%s\"},
          \"subject\": \"%s",
          \"content\": [{\"type\": \"text/plain\", \"value\": \"%s\"}]
            }', 
                to.email, from.email, subject, message.body)

pp <-  POST("https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send",
          body = msg,
          config = add_headers("Authorization" = sprintf("Bearer %s", key1),
                               "Content-Type" = "application/json"),
          verbose())
```

But I can't add few emails in "cc".
After reading documentation https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Mail/index.html it tried code below, but I have "Bad request" reply.

```
msg  <- sprintf('{\"personalizations\":
        [{\"to\": [ %s]}],
        [{\"cc\": [ %s]}],
          \"from\": {\"email\": \"%s\"},
          \"subject\": \"%s",
          \"content\": [{\"type\": \"text/plain\", \"value\": \"%s\"}]
            }', 
                to.email, cc.email, from.email, subject, message.body)
```

I saw solutions for other languages, but not for R.
Any ideas?

Comment: Based on the documentation, you may just need to change assignment of cc.email to `paste0('{\"email\": \"', paste( copiers, collapse = '\"}, {\"email\": \"') ,'\"}')`

Comment: Thank you, I see that it's extra `"cc"` in my example code.
Fixing it I still have `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request` error.

Comment: Are you looking for answer only using `sendgrid` to send emails or are open to any option which allows you to add `cc` in mail ?

Comment: Good question, @RonakShah
I'm open to other options, but curious about `sendgrid "cc"` . 
I used `gmailr`, but after update to v. 1.0.0 it asking me to choose account from only one on this computer and I can't use it in scheduled tasks.
Now I use `sendgrid` but move all address from "cc" to "to" in order to send emails to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1) Using `sendgrid`

For `sendgrid`, we don't need to escape every string with `/`, it is automatically done. Also it is important to construct the request object correctly.

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

key1 <- "SG.***"
body = paste0("\\nDear friend,",
          "\\n\\n",
          "\\n\\nI'm testing email.",
          "\\n\\n",
          "\\n\\nKind regards,",
          "\\n\\nRonak")


readers <- c("email1@example.com", "email2@example.com")
copiers <- c("email3@example.com", "email4@example.com")
to.email <- paste0('{"email": "',paste(readers,collapse = '"}, {"email": "'),'"}')
cc.email <- paste0('{"email": "',paste(copiers,collapse = '"}, {"email": "'),'"}')
from.email <-  "test@example.com"
subject    <-  "Testing Sendgrid"
message.body  <-  body


msg  <- sprintf('{"personalizations":[{
                  "to": [ %s],
                  "cc": [ %s]
                  }],
                 "from\": {"email": "%s"},
                 "subject\": "%s",
                 "content\": [{"type": "text/plain", "value": "%s"}]
                }', to.email, cc.email, from.email, subject, message.body)

POST("https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send",
 body = msg,
 config = add_headers("Authorization" = sprintf("Bearer %s", key1),
                      "Content-Type" = "application/json"),
 verbose())
```

---

### 2) Using `emayili`

Apart from using `sendgrid` there are lot of packages in R which is used to send emails. I used a new package [emayili](https://github.com/datawookie/emayili) to send the email and it worked for me.

The reason why I chose it is because :-

- the package is fairly new and thus overcomes the issues which are present in older packages. The previous packages have lot of difficulty in installation and setting up.
- using it is very straightforward, easy to use syntax

However, the downside is since it is fairly new it is still not available on CRAN and the package needs to be downloaded from github.

```
install.packages("curl")
remotes::install_github("datawookie/emayili")

library(emayili)
library(magrittr)
library(curl)


email <- envelope()
email <- email %>%
         from(c("email1@gmail.com", "email4@gmail.com")) %>%
         to("email2@gmail.com") %>%
         cc("email3@yahoo.com")

email <- email %>% subject("This is a plain text message!")
email <- email %>% body("Hello!")
smtp <- server(host = "smtp.gmail.com",
           port = 587,
           username = "email1@gmail.com",
           password = "password")
smtp(email, verbose = TRUE)
```

I tested this on my personal gmail and yahoo account and the mail came through. You might want to add `verbose = FALSE` if you don't want to flood your console with log messages. Also if you are using gmail you might need to [allow access to less secure apps](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) to send the email.

Comment: Thank you, @RonakShah for trying to help
My company is using gmail and access to less secure apps are not allowed.
That's why I started using `sendgrid` for automatic emails.

Comment: @YuriyBarvinchenko are you able to send email from `sendgrid` at all ? I was trying to use it but I get bad request even without including any `cc` information.

Comment: Yes, I can send email.
Please check it one more time.
There were extra lines in my code regarding attachments, I deleted them (see edited code in question). Sorry, it's impossible to make reproducible question without real credentials.

Comment: @YuriyBarvinchenko Can you check if the updated answer works with `sendgrid` for you ? It worked for me.